# Understanding tkinter tag_bind

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I cannot figure out how to use the `tag_bind` method associated with a canvas. I created an `oval` and expected to be able to generate an `event` by clicking on it. When I do this, nothing happens. What is the correct use of `tag_bind`?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.c = tk.Canvas(self.master, bg='white', height=200, width=300)
        self.c.pack()

        b = tk.Button(self.master, text='Draw', command=self.draw)
        b.pack()

    def draw(self):
        self.c.delete('all')
        self.oval = self.c.create_oval([30,50], [130,80])
        self.rect = self.c.create_rectangle([180,10], [280,80])

        self.c.tag_bind(self.oval, '<Button-1>', self.oval_func)

    def oval_func(self, event):
        self.c.delete(self.rect)
        self.c.create_text(150, 150, text='Hello, world!', anchor='w')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code works for me.  Are you clicking ON the oval or INSIDE the oval?  A click inside does nothing; a click on the oval's outline works.

Comment: @Paul Right, I clicked inside the unfilled oval. Next time I'll fill it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working. However, when you bind to a canvas object, you have to click on part of the drawn object. Since you didn't fill the oval, that means you must click on its outline.

If you fill it with the same color as the background (or any other color) you can click anywhere in the oval.

```
self.oval = self.c.create_oval([30,50], [130,80], fill="white")
```

Comment: The default "fill" value is the empty string, which makes the item "unfilled" and merely the outline of the shape. If you want a solid shape, you must give it some fill color other than the empty string.